# Error Code: 1054: Unknown column 'table_name.column_name' in 'field list' when Table exist

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I am trying to run mySQL query to fetch data from my Database. Following is my query:

```
SELECT user,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'TB' THEN pause_sec END) AS Training_Break,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'SB1' THEN pause_sec END) AS Short_Break_1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'SB2' THEN pause_sec END) AS Short_Break_2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN sub_status = 'LB' THEN pause_sec END) AS Long_Break
FROM vicidial_agent_log
WHERE event_time >= '2021-04-01' AND
      event_time < '2021-04-17' AND
      sub_status IN ('TB', 'SB1', 'SB2', 'LB')
GROUP BY user
HAVING COALESCE(`Training Break`, `Short Break 1`, `Short Break 2`, `Long Break`) IS NOT NULL
```

This produces desired results:
[Table Output on the results.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVeIz.png)
I want to show names of USERS but they are in another table. So, I used join here like as follow:

```
SELECT `vicidial_agent_log.user`,
`vicidial_users.full_name`,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `vicidial_agent_log.sub_status` = 'TB' THEN `vicidial_agent_log.pause_sec` END) AS Training_Break,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `vicidial_agent_log.sub_status` = 'SB1' THEN `vicidial_agent_log.pause_sec` END) AS Short_Break_1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `vicidial_agent_log.sub_status` = 'SB2' THEN `vicidial_agent_log.pause_sec` END) AS Short_Break_2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN `vicidial_agent_log.sub_status` = 'LB' THEN `vicidial_agent_log.pause_sec` END) AS Long_Break
FROM `vicidial_agent_log`
INNER JOIN `vicidial_users` ON `vicidial_users.user`=`vicidial_agent_log.user`
WHERE `vicidial_agent_log.event_time` >= '2021-04-01' AND
      `vicidial_agent_log.event_time` < '2021-04-17' AND
      `vicidial_agent_log.sub_status` IN ('TB', 'SB1', 'SB2', 'LB')
GROUP BY `vicidial_agent_log.user`
HAVING COALESCE(`Training_Break`, `Short_Break_1`, `Short_Break_2`, `Long_Break`) IS NOT NULL
```

And it produces following error:

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'vicidial_agent_log.user' in 'field list'

But the table exists.

Also, if I remove back ticks in my code, it generates this error:

> Error Code: 1054 Unknown column 'vicidial_agent_log.user' in 'group statement'

Following are fields of my two Tables and their columns:

 >Columns of vicidial_agent_log: [agent_log_id, user, ...] 

 >Columns of vicidial_users: [user_id, user, pass, full_name, ...]
My desired output should look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVeIz.png only with an addition of one column with a name on it.

This is the first professional project I am building and any sort of help will do. I must be making a beginners mistake that might be small. I am not sure if there is problem with my logic or concept. I have researched into other posts but it doesn't seem to work for me. Any sort of help will go a long way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't escape your identifiers!  And use aliases!  I think I mentioned this in an earlier answer.  So:

```
SELECT al.user, u.full_name,
      SUM(CASE WHEN al.sub_status = 'TB' THEN al.pause_sec  END) AS Training_Break,
      SUM(CASE WHEN al.sub_status = 'SB1' THEN al.pause_sec END) AS Short_Break_1,
      SUM(CASE WHEN al.sub_status = 'SB2' THEN al.pause_sec END) AS Short_Break_2,
      SUM(CASE WHEN al.sub_status = 'LB' THEN al.pause_sec END) AS Long_Break
FROM vicidial_agent_log al JOIN
     vicidial_users u
     ON u.user = al.user
WHERE al.event_time >= '2021-04-01' AND
      al.event_time < '2021-04-17' AND
      al.sub_status IN ('TB', 'SB1', 'SB2', 'LB')
GROUP BY al.user, u.full_name;
```

The `HAVING` clause is not needed with this version, unless `al.pause_sec` could be `NULL`.  If that is possible, just add `al.pause_sec IS NOT NULL` to the `WHERE` clause.

The problem with your query is that

```
`vicidial_agent_log.user`
```

refers to a column name that has a `.` in it.  You intend:

```
`vicidial_agent_log`.`user`
```

But why bother with the backticks when these are equivalent to:

```
vicidial_agent_log.user
```

Or:

```
al.user
```

when the table alias is defined.

Comment: Thanks man, your explanation made it look so simple. I will absolutely your comments on my OneNote file.